# li:lt(4) is not getting all list items less than the count of 4?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This is my HTML:

```
<ol id="front-page">
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>    </li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
<li>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>
</li>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ol#front-page').find('li:eq(4)').css("margin","0");
$('ol#front-page').find('li:lt(4)').append("<span>New</span>");
```

});

and what I am trying to do is have the first 3 list items to have a span appended to them. It will append the span to the 0 element but not the other 3?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your code works for me and adds the new span to the first 3 elements. Maybe you have some other code not shown here that is interfering? Also, to add the `<span>New</span>` to the beginning, use `prepend` not `append`

Comment: funny because that's the only js I'm running other than google load, the css line works perfectly, it's just getting that span! 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code appends the span after each one of the first 4 li elements. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I need it to append it within the li element for example:
<li>
    <span>New</span>
    <img src="images/defaultImage.gif" alt="Default Image" />
    <a href="#" title="Title Entry">Title Entry</a>    </li>
<li>

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check here (http://jsbin.com/upute) for a demonstration what your code actually does.

This sets `margin` to `0` on the fifth `li` (as the list is zero based)

```
$('ol#front-page').find('li:eq(4)').css("margin","0");
```

This appends (==at the end) the span for the first four li's

```
$('ol#front-page').find('li:lt(4)').append("<span>New</span>");
```

What you probably want to do is this. Set margin to 0 on the fourth element and **prepend** the span to the first four `li`'s.

```
$('ol#front-page').find('li:lt(4)').prepend("<span>New</span>");
```

Comment: Same as above, only the 0 position is getting the span appended to it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so `lt(4)` and `eq(4)` are ok. Did you check the sample on I linked to in my answer. Doesn't that work for you neither? What browser + jQuery version are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'li:lt(4)'` with `'li:lt(3)'`. The :lt() filter works on a zero-based index, so :lt(4) means elements 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Reference: [Selectors/lt @ jQuery API](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index)

P.D. You probably want `'li:eq(3)'` as well

Comment: li:eq(4) is being used since there are 4 list elements to a row, all with 20px of left margin (accept the first-child). So the targeted element is the visual 5th element (or position 4 in js) to prevent the new row from having a left margin on it's starting list item.

li:lt(3) returns the same result, only getting position 0 to have the span appended to it.

Thanks!